# Is there a way to make a "custom" Map through MonoTouch?

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I am interested in making a small "Map-like" application that uses a custom map. I would need to figure out how to:

1) Create a map that has multiple levels of details, so zooming in would create greated detail

2) Make a connection to the Mapping control to allow zoom depth.

Number 2 seems possible without the `MKMapView`. I could just use a generic UIView and control pinch/zoomm events to change the "zoom level" and draw appropriately in the view, however that seems too tricky to pull off, espcially since I don't know how to do #1.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For #2 you can have a look at MonoTouch [ZoommingPdfViewer](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ZoomingPdfViewer) sample (a port of Apple's ObjectiveC sample). It will show you how to use `CALayer` with `UIView` to create the pinch/zoom effect. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can *upvote* answers that are helpful without marking it as accepted (since it's not a full answer).